# Express the Squares of first 20 Numbers with only numbers found in their Sum of Digits

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, calculation-puzzle

Allowed Operations ...Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication, Division, Exponentiation, Simple Factorial. Left and Right Brackets allowed.

Expression should involve minimum number of total characters:

Example:

Number 7.   Square.    49.    Sum of Digits.   13

Using only digits 1 and 3, express 49

One possibility is.    49 =  (3! + 1) * (3! + 1)

Comment: Sure..only restriction is among all the possibilities with allowed signs, come up with minimum footprint

Comment: is square root allowed?

Comment: No..only given signs(operations allowed)

Comment: Are concatenations allowed? E.g. given 13 in your example, could we use the number 13, or only 1 and 3?

Comment: No concatenation..only mentioned operations..in the example, 1 and 3 can be used with any mentioned allowable operations

Comment: Please show for all the squares of first 20 numbers...final answer with least number of characters will get the green check

Comment: I solved all 20 ... now to see if I can reduce any character counts :-)

Comment: Great!  Whoever has lowest character count will get the green check at the end..thx

Comment: If there are 2 digits in sod..both need to be used in the expression

Comment: Will review all the answers so far in another 3 hrs and let you know who has minimum characters

Comment: After reviewing all the answers, JMP’s expressions are most concise and he gets the nod for green check..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1: sod=1

> $1$

4: sod=4

> $4$

9: sod=9

> $9$

16: sod=7

> $(7+\frac77)(\frac{7+7}{7})$

25: sod=7

> $(7-\frac{7+7}{7})^{\frac{7+7}{7}}$

36: sod=9

> $9+9+9+9$

49: sod=13

> $(3!+1)^{1+1}$

64: sod=10

> $(1+1)^{(1+1+1)!}$

81: sod=9

> $9\times9$

100: sod=1

> $((1+1+1)^{1+1}+1))^{1+1}$

121: sod=4

> $(4+\frac44)!+\frac44$

144: sod=9

> $(9-\frac99)(9+9)$

169: sod=16

> $(6+6+1)^{1+1}$

196: sod=16

> $(6+6+1+1)^{1+1}$

225: sod=9

> $9\times(9+9+9)-9-9$

256: sod=13

> $(1+1)^{(1+1)^3}$

289: sod=19

> $(9+9-1)^{1+1}$

324: sod=9

> $(9+9)(9+9)$

361: sod=10

> $\frac{(1+1+1)!!}{1+1}+1$

400: sod=4

> $4\times(4\cdot4!+4)$

Comment: no- the 10 is not allowed... sorry

Comment: No concatenation of 1 and 0 allowed

Comment: why does the 400 case work? 4.4! is like 48 point something

Comment: using dot notation for multiply @OmegaKrypton

Comment: good game! +1 JMP!

Answer (score 2):

Partial

notation: sod = sum of digits, sq = square

1) sq=1, sod=1

> $1=1$

2) sq=4, sod=4

> $4=4$

3) sq=9, sod=9

> $9=9$

4) sq=16, sod=7

> $16=7+7+7/7+7/7$

5) sq=25, sod=7

> 

6) sq=36, sod=9

> $36=9+9+9+9$

7) sq=49, sod=13

> $49=(3!+1)*(3!+1)$ (from OP)

8) sq=64, sod=10

> $64=\big((1+1)^{(1+1+1)}\big)^{(1+1)}$

17) sq=289, sod=19

> 289=(9+9-1)^(1+1)

18) sq=324, sod=9

> 324=(9+9)^(9/9+9/9)

Comment: @omega..answers for 19 and 20 missing

Comment: @Uvc sorry, didnt bother to finish this while Rand and JMP have finished... ;)

Comment: Still..whatever you have done is pretty good.

Answer (score 2):

1. Square 1. Sum of digits 1.

   > $1=1$.
2. Square 4. Sum of digits 4.

   > $4=4$.
3. Square 9. Sum of digits 9.

   > $9=9$.
4. Square 16. Sum of digits 7.

   > $16=7+7+\frac{7}{7}+\frac{7}{7}$.
5. Square 25. Sum of digits 7.

   > $25=\frac{(7\times7)+\frac{7}{7}}{\frac{7}{7}+\frac{7}{7}}$.
6. Square 36. Sum of digits 9.

   > $36=9+9+9+9$.
7. Square 49. Sum of digits 13.

   > $49=(3!+1)\times(3!+1)$.
8. Square 64. Sum of digits 10.

   > $64=(1+1+1+1)^{1+1+1}$.
9. Square 81. Sum of digits 9.

   > $81=9\times9$.
10. Square 100. Sum of digits 1.

    > $100=((1+1+1+1+1)\times(1+1))^{1+1}$.
11. Square 121. Sum of digits 4.

    > $121=(4+4+4-\frac{4}{4})^{\frac{4}{4}+\frac{4}{4}}$.
12. Square 144. Sum of digits 9.

    > $144=9\times(9+9)-9-9$.
13. Square 169. Sum of digits 16. (Most interesting one!)

    > $169=(6-1)!+(6+1)^{1+1}$.
14. Square 196. Sum of digits 16.

    > $196=(6+6+1+1)^{1+1}$.
15. Square 225. Sum of digits 9.

    > $225=9\times(9+9+9)-9-9$.
16. Square 256. Sum of digits 13.

    > $256=(3+1)^{3+1}$.
17. Square 289. Sum of digits 19.

    > $289=(9+9-1)^{1+1}$.
18. Square 324. Sum of digits 9.

    > $324=(9+9)\times(9+9)$.
19. Square 361. Sum of digits 10.

    > $361=\frac{(1+1+1+1+1+1)!}{1+1}+1$.
20. Square 400. Sum of digits 4.

    > $400=4\times(4\times4!+4)$.

Comment: good game! +1 Rand!